# How to change the URL after a navigation using jQuery Mobile's $.mobile.navigate

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery Mobile and I've been trying so hard (been googling for 2 days straight) to understand how the navigation to external pages works but finding it really hard so hopefully I can get a proper explanation here. From my searches I've found the `$.mobile.navigate` function but I haven't quite figured out how exactly to use it.

Basically what I have is a `login.php` page, after you successfully logged in you should be taken to the `homepage.php`, I've managed to make it so that the `homepage.php`'s content is shown, but when it comes to the URL I can see for a split second that it changes to `homepage.php` but immidiately changes back to `login.php`. How can I make it so that it stays on `homepage.php`?

I navigate to `homepage.php` with `$.mobile.navigate` like so:

```
<input type="submit" form="login-form" name="submit_login" value="Logga in" id="submit-login">

$('body').on('click', '#submit-login', function() {
    $.mobile.navigate('../../includes/pages/homepage.php');
});
```

And currently my `homepage.php` file looks like this:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="homepage" data-theme="b" id="homepage">
    <div data-role="header">Some content here</div>
    <div data-role="main">Some content here</div>
    <div data-role="footer">Some content here</div>
</div>
```

I read somewhere that `data-url` is used for changing the url on navigation but I haven't been able to make any use of it from my attempts.

Comment: Can you please post the code defining the `submit-login` button?

Comment: Can you try replacing the `navigate` call with `$("body").pagecontainer("change", "../../includes/pages/homepage.php");`?

Comment: @Sga that sends me to the homepage but then straight back to login, the url changes as it should however.

Comment: You can try two things: disable ajax navigation or changing the button to a plain `<a href="#" data-type="button">Login</a>` (just guessing, can't try in a PHP environment right now)

Comment: @Sga Disabling ajax isn't an option since all the error handling doesn't work then, and using a normal <a> tag wouldn't post the login information. Seems strange that I'm the only one that seems to get this problem because haven't been able to find an answer anywhere..